# Custom workflow editor to C#

Tags: c#, xml, uml, activity-diagram

In my free time, I am trying to make my home automation project "easily" customizable. So that I can explain my kids how things work.

Current state of the project:
I got devices (arduino's) that serve a function, like controlling a LED or locking and unlocking doors.

These devices communicate throught a MQTT Broker with my desktop client that is running a C# program.

Every device has a uniquid ID (MACAddress) and a set of functions: LED on, LED off, etc.

I am creating a XML File that consists of every device in the network. Looking like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DeviceList>
    <Device>
        <FriendlyName>LockFrontdoor</FriendlyName>
        <Uid>D1-56-D4-93-94-EC</Uid>
        <ControllerType>Doorlock</ControllerType>
        <ControlList>
            <Control>
                <Name>LockOn</Name>
                <Command>/Lock/On</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>LockOff</Name>
                <Command>/Lock/Off</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getLockState</Name>
                <Command>/Lock/getState</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getDoorState</Name>
                <Command>/Door/getState</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getDeviceState</Name>
                <Command>/getState</Command>
            </Control>
        </ControlList>
        <EventList>
            <Event>
                <Name>Disconnected</Name>
                <Command>/Disconnected</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>Connected</Name>
                <Command>/Connected</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>LockStateOn</Name>
                <Command>/Lockstate/On</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>LockStateOff</Name>
                <Command>/Lockstate/Off</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>DoorOpen</Name>
                <Command>/Doorstate/Open</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>DoorClosed</Name>
                <Command>/Doorstate/Closed</Command>
            </Event>
        </EventList>
    </Device>
    <Device>
        <FriendlyName>LightFrontdoor</FriendlyName>
        <Uid>89-C9-7C-D8-B5-34</Uid>
        <ControllerType>Led</ControllerType>
        <ControlList>
            <Control>
                <Name>On</Name>
                <Command>/LED/On</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>Off</Name>
                <Command>/LED/Off</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>Blink</Name>
                <Command>/LED/Blink</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>Color</Name>
                <Command>/LED/Color/1-255,1-255,1-255</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>Intensity</Name>
                <Command>/LED/Intensity/1-255</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getState</Name>
                <Command>/LED/getState</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getDeviceState</Name>
                <Command>/getState</Command>
            </Control>
        </ControlList>
        <EventList>
            <Event>
                <Name>Disconnected</Name>
                <Command>/Disconnected</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>Connected</Name>
                <Command>/Connected</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>LedStateOn</Name>
                <Command>/LedState/On</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>LedStateOff</Name>
                <Command>/LedState/Off</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>LedStateBlink</Name>
                <Command>/LedState/Blink</Command>
            </Event>
        </EventList>
    </Device>
    <Device>
        <FriendlyName>SpeakerFrontDoor</FriendlyName>
        <Uid>F8-87-66-D3-81-E0</Uid>
        <ControllerType>Audio</ControllerType>
        <ControlList>
            <Control>
                <Name>PlaySound1</Name>
                <Command>/Audio/PlaySound1</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>PlaySound2</Name>
                <Command>/Audio/PlaySound2</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getState</Name>
                <Command>/Audio/getState</Command>
            </Control>
            <Control>
                <Name>getDeviceState</Name>
                <Command>/getState</Command>
            </Control>
        </ControlList>
        <EventList>
            <Event>
                <Name>Disconnected</Name>
                <Command>/Disconnected</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>Connected</Name>
                <Command>/Connected</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>SoundStatePlaying</Name>
                <Command>/Audio/On</Command>
            </Event>
            <Event>
                <Name>SoundStateNotPlaying</Name>
                <Command>/Audio/Off</Command>
            </Event>
        </EventList>
    </Device>
</DeviceList>
```

I also created a parralel sequence (Example):
[UML Activity Diagram for the automation project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNt6Q.png)

Now what I want to do, is create an editor that can import my XML and where you can create/edit the UML and export this UML in a format that I can import in my C# client to work with the devices.

I know this is probably really difficult, but I am not sure where to start. Is there any software that already can do this for a normal price? Or is there a way to do this easily?

I have searched on Google and found https://workflowengine.io which seems a perfect solution. However, I would need to pay $5,000 which I can't at the moment. I do have enough free time though.

So, what would be a good approach to create this? Or is there a framework or software that already does this?

Comment: Question is offtopic. But look at [Camunda](https://camunda.com/download/), this is in java but free.

Comment: [Wexflow](https://github.com/aelassas/Wexflow) is C# and open source. But generally stackoverflow is not for recommending tools.